# 2 target columns in H2O driverless AI

Tags: h2o, driverless-ai

how should I use H2O DAI on 2 target columns? Current version (AMI ID: h2oai-driverless-ai-1.0.19 (ami-46e5dd3c)) only allows 1 target column. The 2 target columns of interest are both float64 type. Thanks.

Comment: why not run two experiments and exclude the 2nd target during the first experiment, and then exclude the 1st column from the second experiment?

Comment: I did try that and it can work. But I wonder how much improvement can be made by predicting on both columns. btw the columns are latitude and longitude.

Comment: try to approximate location by ordered squared areas of appropriate resolution - that'll compress your target into a single value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently H2O DAI only supports one target. (As noted in the comments you can run two separate experiments, for ideas on how to handle predicting lat and long the following kaggle competition may be of interesthttps://www.kaggle.com/c/pkdd-15-predict-taxi-service-trajectory-i/).